# Warp Persist alternative

Tags: java, guice

Has anybody run into an alternative to warp-persist?

http://code.google.com/p/warp-persist/

It seems like there is no longer development on warp-persist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not out yet, but the first version of guice-persist (based on warp-persist and by Dhanji Prasanna, its author) has been checked into the guice codebase [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/#svn/trunk/extensions/persist/src/com/google/inject/persist).